# How would I print the index of an array? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing, printing

I was just wondering how do I print off the Index position of an array? I know there's an if loop involved but I just can't seem to understand it properly.
I want the code to be able to print off what the element of the Array is and the position number. I should also mention that this is for a function as well. Any help will be appreciated. Below is my code

```
int index_of(string names[], int size)
{
    string name;
    int index;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (to_lowercase (names[i]) == to_lowercase(name));
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Printing something is pretty easy. Please post a [mre] to  clarify what problem you've encountered. And please clarify how the shown (buggy) code is related to the problem. Seein expected and actual output will also help.

Comment: Sidenote: that code is broken (maybe that's what you are asking?) The return type is `int`, but you don't return an int. Did you mean `return i;`? If the string is not found the function ends without returning anytihng - which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: It looks like this function should take `name` as an argument, because as-is all it can do is search `names` for an empty string.

Comment: @NathanPierson Good point, which I missed in my answer. Will you make one or can I extend my answer with it?

Comment: thanks for commenting fellas, all of your combined contributions actually did manage to get it working,  and in case anyone was wondering I will post the answer to what managed to end up working below

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called "searching".
You have a string which (potentially) is the known content of an entry in an array, but at an unknown index.
What you need to do is to find the index which, used for accessing the entry at that index, yields content which is identical to what you are looking for.
The code you show is more or less pseudo code for doing exactly that.

However, the shown code will not work for the following reasons:

- it does  not correctly return the index in question, it should `return i;`
- it only returns explicitly in case of finding something, it should, after the loop, `return -1;`(as a proposal how to communicate failure)
- it incorrectly compares (the `==` operator cannot meaningfully be used on "strings", which in C are only pointers to characters), it should use `strncmp()`, see e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp
- it does not actually print anything, but I think that is a problem of phrasing your goal and you can easily add a print outside of the shown code, using the (now hopefully correct and correctly returned) return value of the shown function
- it has the problem mentioned by Nathan Pierson, see their comment/answer

Comment: Not sure about the third point, looks like OP is using `std::string` all the way. Allthough, not sure what `to_lowercase` is or returns.

Answer (score 0):

This is what managed to print the indexes, you guys were actually able to help me understand what I was doing

```
int index_of(string names[], int size, string name)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (to_lowercase (names[i]) == to_lowercase(name));
        {
            return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: But it's still wrong, it will _always_ return in the first iteration of the loop. You want to return -1, only if no item was found. That is, when the return inside the loop was not reached. So it has to be outside the loop to work.